# Puede ser que un textarea me genere problemas al enviar un correo electrónico?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Tengo un formulario de envío típico:

```
<form class="ui form" role="form" action="envio.php" method="POST" accept-charset="utf-8" autocomplete="off">
<div class="ui segment">

    <div class="three fields">
        <div class="field">
            <label>Nombre de Usuario:</label>
            <input id="usuario" type="text" name="usuario" value="<?php echo $row['usuario']; ?>">
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <label>Nombre y Apellido:</label>
            <input id="nombre" type="text" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $row['nombre']; ?>" >
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <label>Correo Electrónico:</label>
            <input id="email" type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $row['correo']; ?>" >
        </div>

        <div class="field">
            <label>Id Usuario:</label>
            <input name="id" id="id" type="text" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <label>Asunto:</label>
        <input id="asunto" type="text" name="asunto">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <textarea id="cuerpo" type="textarea" name="cuerpo" rows=15 ></textarea>
    </div>

    <!--Botones de envío de la información-->
    <button type="submit" name="save" class="ui green icon button">
      <i class="send icon"></i>
      Enviar
    </button>

</div>
</form>
```

El textarea tiene adjunto un control tinyMCE. Les cuento el problema que tengo:
Cuando pongo un texto sin ningun tipo de "enriquecimiento de texto" léase negritas, cursivas, saltos de linea el envío me genera un error 403. Si envío texto sin esos caracteres, es decir, coloco una oración con acentos pero sin saltos de linea ni cambio de caracteres, lo envía perfectamente.

el archivo envio.php tiene lo siguiente:

```
<?php
require '../../../includes/conexion.php';
include '../../../includes/funcs_pdo.php';

$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];    
$email = $_POST['email'];
$asunto = $_POST['asunto'];

$allowedTags='<p><strong><em><u><h1><h2><h3><h4><h5><h6><img><li><ol><ul><span><div><br><ins><del><small><a><em><strong><small><s><cite><q><dfn><abbr><ruby><rt><rp><data><time><code><var><samp><kbd><sub><sup><i><b><u><mark><bdi>
<bdo><span><br><wbr>';

$cuerpo = strip_tags($_POST['cuerpo'],$allowedTags);

if(enviarEmailST($email, $nombre, $asunto, $cuerpo)){
    // Si se envió el correo electronico
    echo "El envío del correo electrónico fue correcto";
} else {
    // Si no se pudo enviar el correo electronico
    echo "Hubo un error al enviar el correo electrónico";
}
?>
```

Probé sacar el tinyMCE y dejar un textarea simple, sin modificaciones y también envía bien las cosas. Pero cuando le coloco etiquetas html de salto de línea también me genera el mismo error.
Lo más extraño es que en el phpmailer tengo definido

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

a alguien le ha pasado esto ?

Answer (score 0):

Gracias a todos por su ayuda sin igual, pude resolver el problema. En una de las definiciones del phpmailer solamente tuve que poner

```
$mail->Body = html_entity_decode($cuerpo);
```

y santo remedio, acepta todos las etiquetas html